# How to manage a stop or restart of a task from Django-based site?

Tags: django, asynchronous

I'll be running a script in a server which will automatically create model instances in a database. The idea is to use a infinite loop (e.g while True:) which will be endlessly creating instances until I somehow  stop it.
I want to use Django to nicely check from my website how big my database is, and from there I want to stop or restart it.
What could be a good approach here?
I was thinking about Celery, but I don't know how would I don't have clear how to stop it and it kind of looks like an overkill. Any suggestion?

Comment: One way is to create a simple flag model with two fields: `name` and `value`. Create an entry maybe `Flag(name="RUN_LOOP", value=True)`. Then have your infinite loop check that instead of while True.

Comment: Let me know if that's along the lines you're thinking of, I'll pseudocode an answer for you.

Comment: How could I stop the loop with this? Because I want to leave the process working for days without the need to leave my session/browser open. 

If I understand this would let the process checking for the attribute "value" to change, but will it continue if I close my browser or move to a different page?

Comment: If your script is running as a process on the server, for example as a management command, then you don't need to have a browser open to continue running. Within the looping code, you would insert a check to the db for a specific "flag" or some criteria that would let the script know you want it to stop running.

Comment: That sounds like what I'm looking for @Ben; how can I insert the "check" your talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to have a class that saves to the db the name of the script and whether it should keep running:

```
class ScriptTracker():
    name = models.Charfield()
    keep_running = models.BooleanField()
```

Then your script would just check the db every loop to see if it should stop:

```
def my_script():

    while True:

        if not ScriptTracker.objects.get(name="my_script").keep_running:
            # stop running
            return

        # creating an instance in the db
        MyObject.objects.create(name="helloworld")
```

1. Create the ScriptTracker object

`ScriptTracker.objects.create(name="my_script", keep_running=True)`

2. Start your script running, could be done simple if script is built as a management command:

`python manage.py my_script`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is exactly what I was looking for.